# String to linked list using double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

I have the following code
I"m converting the string stored into the linked list.
Example : ABC
A->B->C->NULL

**Problems** :
When printing the list,it is not giving the desired output.Following is the code and sample input/outputs.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    char ch;
    struct node *next;
}node;
void create(node **head,char ch)
{
    node *new;
    new=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->next=NULL;
    new->ch=ch;
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        *head=new;
        printf("%c",(*head)->ch);
        return ;
    }
    while((*head)->next)
    {
        (*head)=(*head)->next;
    }
    (*head)->next=new;


}
void printList(node *head)
{
    printf("\nThe list has - ");
    while(head)
    {
        printf("%c",head->ch);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
int main()
{
    node *head=NULL;
    int i=0;
    char *str=NULL;
    str=malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
    printf("\nEnter the string - ");
    scanf("%s",str);

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        create(&head,str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input/Outputs**

**Input 1**

```
Enter the string - abc 
a
The list has - bc
```

**Input 2**

```
Enter the string - abcde
a
The list has - de
```

**Input 3**

```
Enter the string - ab
a
The list has - ab
```

**Note :**

If I change my create function to this , everything just works fine!.
I want to know what’s the difference here?
Has it something to do with the double pointer??

```
void create(node **head,char ch)
{
    node *new,*ptr;
    new=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->next=NULL;
    new->ch=ch;
    ptr=*head;
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        ptr=new;
        return;
    }
    while(ptr->next)
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next=new;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You do not describe the desired output

Comment: @user590028 isn't it obvious..I said I'm trying to copy the string into a linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a issue with your insert function in the first code snipper where you move the `*head` so by the time you insert the last node to the list the head is pointing to one before the last node

```
a->b->c->d
      |
      |

Head is at c now
```

So you should never move the head and just use temporary variable to get the value of head and move temp.

```
a->b->c->d
|     |
|     |
Head  temp
```

> Has it something to do with the double pointer??

No it is just that in the second snippet you use `ptr` as temporary pointer and doesn't move head your code works as shown above.

Comment: Since I'm using the condition `(*head->next)` inside `while` loop, so the loop should exit when `(*head)` should point to `d` and `(*head->next=NULL)`. Why is the loop exiting when head is pointing to `c`?

Comment: @NitinPandey When (*head) is pointing to c `(*head)->next = NULL`.. Thats when you go ahead and add a node(d) so now your `*head` stays there .. Got it?

Comment: Ohh!! Yes Yes..What was i thinking?? Got it ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gopi has already pointed out the issue with your code. You can use that advice to insert a new node if you distinguish between the two cases of inserting the first node to an empty list (in which case you must update `head`) and of appending to an existing list. (You already catch the two cases.)

But the pointer-to-pointer strategy adds one level of indirection, which you can use here to do without this distinction: `head` holds the pointer to the pointer to the head node. If you use `head` to walk through the list, `head` should always point to the pointer that points to the current node. When the current node is `NULL`, assign the new node, i.e. overwrite the pointer:

```
void create(node **head, char ch)
{
    /* create new node */
    node *nd = malloc(sizeof(*nd));
    nd->next=NULL;
    nd->ch=ch;

    /* advance to end of list */
    while (*head) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }

    /* assign */
    *head = nd;
}
```

By the way, your second function does not work just fine, because you never update the head. You'll get an empty list and memory leaks.

Comment: It works because I'm never changing the head and using a temporary pointer `ptr` to traverse the list and I'm inserting at the end. So is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: When I run your code and replace the `create` function with the one in your last code snippet, I get what I expect: an empty list. Traversing a list with a temporary pointer is okay, because you don't alter the list. But when the list can be changed, you must reflect the updates. The crucial case here is when you add the first node to an empty list: `head` must change; it can't be `NULL` after insertion. After that, your approach works, because you alter a value in the node structure.

Comment: Oh I've a slight different code , you're right I forgot to put `*head=new' in `(ptr==NULL)' section in second code snippet. In my laptop I have so working there! Noticed Just now